# Given a series of data, find the duration limit of given time period?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a collector which collects acceleration with a certain frequency. I want to plot the max duration where the **x label** is a period of time.

The calculation of duration should be like this: 
Take the min value in a period and compare all these values for the time period window slides from beginning to the end to get the max value.

The following code as example plots the duration value when the time period is from **0.001s to 1s**. Is there a way to reduce the time complexity to **O(nlogn)** or even less? In my raw data the array is too long for my algorithm to calculate.

Thanks for help!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t=np.linspace(0,6.27,1000) #collect a value every 0.001s
y=np.sin(t)+1
plt.plot(t,y) ##original curve
yy=[]
for dt in np.arange(1,1000):
    max_duration = max(list((map(lambda i: min((y[i:i + dt])),range(1000)))))
    yy.append(max_duration)

plt.plot(np.arange(1,1000),yy)  ##calculated curve
```

Comment: `y[i:i + dt]` will have a variable number of elements as `dt` increases for the latter `i` values, is that right? Shouldn't all windows have the same size (e.g. using `range(1000 - dt + 1)` in `map`)?

Comment: Yes. in one loop, the size of window keeps unchanged. But I need to plot the duration in all windows whose width varies from 0.001s, 0.002s ... to 6.27s

Comment: Please edit clarifications into your main posting (above).

Comment: Could you please include a restricted example?  You're sliding from one partially-defined term to another, and I'm not quite catching what you need for output.  Perhaps 10 values with a window size of 3, for example?